# Contact form using email class

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am so new at codeigniter. But I am working on a contact form. I want that let visitor fulfill the form (input name,email and message) then when they send the message must come into my inbox.

This is my controller:

```
public function ilet(){
        $name    = $this->input->post("name");
        $email   = $this->input->post("email");
        $message = $this->input->post("message");

        $config = array(
            "protocol"    => "smtp",
            "smtp_host"   => "ssl://smtp.gmail.com",
            "smtp_port"   =>"465",
            "smtp_user"   =>$email,
            "starttls"    =>true,
            "charset"     =>"utf-8",
            "mailtype"    =>"html",
            "wordwrap"    => true,
            "newline"     =>"\r\n",
        );

        $this->load->library("email", $config);

         $this->mail->from($email);
         $this->email->to("cugurel7@gmail.com");
         $this->email->subject("Müşteri bilgi mesajı");
         $this->email->message($message);

         $send = $this->email->send();

         if($send)
         {
             echo "Mail gönderme işlemi başarılı";
         }
         else {
             echo "Başarısız";
         }


    }
```

this is my view:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="/yansayfa/ilet" method="POST" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group" ">
                            <label for="form_name">Adınız Soyadınız</label>
                            <input  style="border-radius: 0px;" id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="İsim & Soyisim" 
                                   >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="form_lastname">E-posta</label>
                            <input style="border-radius: 0px;" id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="E-posta">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="form_message">Mesajınız *</label>
                            <textarea style="border-radius: 0px;" id="message" name="message" class="form-control"
                                      placeholder="Mesaj Giriniz..." rows="4" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="submit" id="mybtn" style="border-radius: 0px;" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Gönder">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

but it seems error and i checked but i dont know where is my error. Can u please help me?

Comment: use this `$this->email->print_debugger();` in else part this will give u any error with email sending and also u r missing `smtp_pass`

Comment: Is your output "Mail gönderme işlemi başarılı" or "Başarısız"?

Comment: Yes these are result outpu

Comment: Which *one* of those two outputs do you see? It can't be both.

Comment: Mail gönderme işlemi başarılı if it is successfull, other one for otherwise

Comment: I know that. But what one do you get **when you run this code?**

Comment: unsuccessfull :/